# How can I enumerate Applications?

Tags: python, windows

I'd like to get information like window name, process, creation time and such under windows XP system.
How can I do it? Is there a module that may give me that information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Python bindings for the Win32 API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).  For the rest, I've had better luck with the Win32 API's documentation than that of the Python bindings.  For your process enumeration task, take a look at the documentation on [Process Information (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684870%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I've wondered if the 32 stands for the 32bit. If it's so, then for an 64-bit system I'll need a Win64 API?

Comment: No; the "32" was to distinguish the API from the older 16-bit Windows API (pre-Windows 95).  There was no reason to devise a new API for 64-bit CPUs, so no Win64 API.

Comment: @geekosaur: It's more like they re-designed the entire operating system when they switched to 32-bit and the older API did not map very well on the new design.  There has been some internal adaptation since then, but there was no re-design at that scale for 64-bit systems.

Comment: Well, yes.  But that's just adding detail.